# Shopware 6 - useProductSearch in product detail page - manufacturer is null

Tags: vuejs3, progressive-web-apps, shopware, headless, nuxt3

I'm using the shopware Nuxt3 pwa to build an headless e-commerce. I am now building the product page inside the  component. The product object within the page is inherited from the  component, which is also responsible for fetching the product data through this script:

```
const { search } = useProductSearch();

const { data: productResponse } = await useAsyncData(
  "cmsProduct" + props.navigationId,
  async () => {
    const productResponse = await search(props.navigationId, {
      withCmsAssociations: true,
    });
    return productResponse;
  },
);
```

Problem is, manufacturer is always null, despite being set in the backend. So much so that in the product listing page I have it filled.

Why is that? Do I need to specify extra parameters within the fetch call?

Thank you

I cannot directly edit the api, I am expecting the manufacturer object to be filled